# How do I cash in my Barry medal in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I finished all missions but didn't cash in my medal right away. Now I'm stuck on level 15? Is there a way to still cash it in?

Answer (score 3):

Start a level, then hit pause.

Comment: ...you can't possibly miss that.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but when I do, the missions window pops up. I have enough missions completed to get level 15 but there is still the mission left where you have to go 1750 meters without collecting any coins. Where or what do I press to cash it in or do I have to complete the last mission? Like I said I've already completed level 15 but I passed up the option to cash in.

Comment: you have to complete the mission, you could unlock that mission for 10,000, 15,000, or 20,000 coins.

Answer (score 1):

Go to where it says "Missions" after you die and it will say cash in.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the pause menu where the missions are normally located and hit cash in. Personally though, I cashed in my level immediately when I got the chance, knowing that I would get A MAN, MY SON for cashing in the levels.