# Where is the prestige option on Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I cash in my Barry medal in Jetpack Joyride?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/how-do-i-cash-in-my-barry-medal-in-jetpack-joyride)

I hear people saying you can prestige but I can't find that option on my iPod. Help?

Comment: Hi @Aaron!  Welcome to Arqade! I voted to close this question, since it looks to me like an exact duplicate of the question Ben referenced.  If you disagree, please check the other question and provide some more details on why your question is different.